# Nokogiri XML builder - save options

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am building XML with Nokogiri with the option of not having empty tags:

```
doc.to_xml(save_with: Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_EMPTY_TAGS)
```

It indeed works for removing empty tags, however passing this option to `to_xml` removes all of my indentation, new line characters etc.

Is there a way to tell Nokogiri to same with NO_EMPTY_TAGS but keeping the rest of the defaults?

Help is kindly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform an `or` operation on your options' bits.

```
doc.to_xml(save_with: Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::AS_XML | Nokogiri::XML::Node::SaveOptions::NO_EMPTY_TAGS)
```

This will apply the defaults of `AS_XML` and the additional setting of `NO_EMPTY_TAGS`